# How do Take .jpg images from an xml file and automatically list them one under another in HTML without having to write every link manually?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an online xml file and have to get the .jpg images from it to automatically display one under another in HTML. I don't want to assign every link manually, because there are A LOT of those images.

I am quite new to this, but have to get it done and i am completely lost. I searched for some answers on google but can't seem to find them. If someone could send a code for the problem it would really help.

**This is what I found on the internet**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
// Assuming you have the XML file stored at the URL 'xmlFileUrl
fetch(https:www.anlux.pl/xml?id=34&hash=70e8721513db4762df3c83c1f758731d2a1ebb95286b0482b4d7a5c0dcfc52c6)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(xmlText => {
    // Parse the XML
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml");

    // Extract the image URLs with ".jpg" extension from the XML
    const imageElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image");
    const imageUrls = Array.from(imageElements)
      .map(element => element.textContent)
      .filter(url => url.endsWith(".jpg"));

    // Display the images
    const imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");
    imageUrls.forEach(imageUrl => {
      const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
      imgElement.src = imageUrl;
      imageContainer.appendChild(imgElement);
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="image-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```